# Changing variable every time function is called

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to make simple tic-tac-toe game. I have a function that places a symbol every time I click on the grid. I have 2 variables for different symbols `xSym` and `circlSym`. I need to change the placed symbol from one to another, every time function `mouseClicked` is called. Is it possible to do so without any return from a function?

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int r = e.getY() / cellH;
    int c = e.getX() / cellW;
    print(r, c, (char)xSym);
    refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a `boolean` member variable `isX` to represent the current state. When `isX` is set, `xSym` is selected; otherwise, `circleSym` is selected.

Each time end-user clicks your app, change `isX`'s state to the opposite. You can use the NOT `!` operator for this, as follows:

```
boolean isX = true; // X moves first
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    char currentSym = isX ? xSym : circleSym;
    isX = !isX; // Invert isX
    int r = e.getY() / cellH;
    int c = e.getX() / cellW;
    print(r, c, currentSym);
    refresh();
}
```

Variable `currentSym` represents the current symbol selected based on the value of `isX` variable.